# Excel chart x-axis not showing correct beginning of month

Tags: excel

In Excel, I have data for the last year on Nasdaq100 adjusted close.

[image]

The issue here is that, if I choose the mmm-yy format for the x-axis, the month ticks will be on the 17th of each month, instead of the beginning.

What should I do to make them refer to the beginning of each month?

Thank you.

Comment: In the Format Axis pane, under `bounds`, set the minimum to `1/5/2021` and the maximum to `1/6/2022` (from the snippet it seems that your version requires `d/m/yyyy` input). Of course, your line will start a bit later and end a bit sooner this way. I'm not sure whether that can be remedied.

Comment: Hi @ouroboros1, thank you for the reply. That is what I currently do actually, but the problem is that it isn't dynamic.
This data is updated everyday and the intention is to show the last year only. I have been searching a solution for really long time actually; it must be very simple but so far I got nothing.

Comment: Hmm. How is the data updated? Are new dates added underneath, or is it always a range with just 1 year of info? Is VBA an option? You can reset the bounds with VBA quite easily. E.g. you could create a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` and then some code to set `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = start_date` & `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = end_date`